# One item gets deleted while iterating an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, ienumerable

I have a method that takes an IEnumerable, filters it further and loops through the filtered collection
to modify one property.

I am observing a very weird behaviour.

While the method loops through the filtered `IEnumerable<Entity>`, after a few iterations (I've not exactly counted how many), 
one of the items in it gets deleted.

```
private async Task<bool> UpdateSomeValue(IEnumerable<BusinessEntity> entities, BusinessEntity entityToDelete)
{
    //FIlter the IENumerable
        var entitiesToUpdateSequence = entities
                .Where(f => f.Sequence > entityToDelete.Sequence);

        if (entitiesToUpdateSequence.Any())
        {
                var testList = new List<FormBE>(entitiesToUpdateSequence);

                Debug.WriteLine(entitiesToUpdateSequence.Count()); // 5

                //DUring this loop, after a few iterations, one item gets deleted
                foreach (var entity in testList)
                {
                        entity.Sequence -= 1;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(entitiesToUpdateSequence.Count()); // 4
                return await _someRepo.UpdateEntitySequence(entityToDelete.Id1, entityToDelete.ID2, testList);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

THis method is called like this:

```
var entities = await entitiesTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
var entityToDelete = entities.Single(f => f.Key.Equals("someValue"));
var updated = await UpdateSomeValue(entities, entityToDelete);
```

and that's it, there's no other reference to the `entities` collection. Therefore, it cannot be modified from any other thread.

I've temprorarily found a word around by copy the filtered IEnumerable in a List and then using the List for further operation
(List content remains the same after the loop).

What may be causing this issue?

Comment: Why do you do `return await Task.FromResult(true);` when `return true;` would do the same thing?

Comment: "one of the items in it gets deleted." - no, it doesn't get deleted. Presumably, its particular `Sequence` is equal to `entityToDelete.Sequence + 1`. When you subtract 1 from that, it's no longer greater than it so when you re-query the items, it no longer matches your `Where` predicate.

Comment: foreach would throw an exception, if a list is modified, while the iterator runs, you cannot even delete anything by intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__). Specifically, the Remarks.

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

Which means that when you call `Where` you're not necessarily getting back an object such as a `List` or `Array` that just has X number of items in it. You're getting back an object that knows how to filter the `IEnumerable<T>` you called `Where` on, based on the predicate you provided. When you iterate that object, such as with a `foreach` loop or a call to `Enumerable.Count()` each item in the source `IEnumerable<T>` is evaluated against the predicate you provided and only the items that satisfy that predicate are returned.

Since the predicate you're providing checks the `Sequence` property, and you're modifying that property inside the first `foreach` loop, the second time you iterate `entitiesToUpdateSequence` fewer items match the predicate you provided and so you get a lower count. If you were to increment `Sequence` instead of decrement it, you might end up with a higher count the second time you iterate `entitiesToUpdateSequence`.

Comment: An easy way to force the `Where` to evaluate is to call `ToList()` on it: `entities.Where(f => f.Sequence > entityToDelete.Sequence).ToList()`. Then it will be calculated only once and won't be recalculated every time you refer to `entitiesToUpdateSequence`.